# Storing multiple objects in an HDFStore group

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

I want to store multiple objects in an HDFStore, but I want to organize it by grouping. Something along the lines of:

```
import pandas as pd
my_store = pd.HDFStore('my_local_store.h5')
my_store._handle.createGroup('/', 'data_source_1') # this works, but I'm not sure what it does
my_store['/data_source_1']['part-1'] = pd.DataFrame({'b':[1,2,9,2,3,5,2,5]}) # this does not work
my_store['/data_source_1']['part-2'] = pd.DataFrame({'b':[3,8,4,2,5,5,6,1]}) # this does not work either
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
my_store['/data_source_1/part-1'] = ...
```

demo:

```
In [13]: store = pd.HDFStore('c:/temp/stocks.h5')

In [15]: store['/aaa/bbb'] = df

In [17]: store.groups
Out[17]:
<bound method HDFStore.groups of <class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: c:/temp/stocks.h5
/aaa/bbb            frame        (shape->[3,7])
/stocks             wide_table   (typ->appendable,nrows->6,ncols->3,indexers->[major_axis,minor_axis],dc->[AAPL,ABC,GOOG])>

In [18]: store['/aaa/bbb2'] = df

In [20]: store.items
Out[20]:
<bound method HDFStore.items of <class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: c:/temp/stocks.h5
/aaa/bbb             frame        (shape->[3,7])
/aaa/bbb2            frame        (shape->[3,7])
/stocks              wide_table   (typ->appendable,nrows->6,ncols->3,indexers->[major_axis,minor_axis],dc->[AAPL,ABC,GOOG])>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [29]: store.get_node('/aaa')
Out[29]:
/aaa (Group) ''
  children := ['bbb' (Group), 'bbb2' (Group)]
```

PS AFAIK Pandas considers `key` (`/aaa/bbb`) as a full path

**UPDATE2:** listing the store:

we have the following store:

```
In [19]: store
Out[19]:
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: D:\temp\.data\hdf\test_groups.h5
/data_source_1/subdir1/1            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->3,indexers->[index])
/data_source_1/subdir1/2            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->3,indexers->[index])
/data_source_1/subdir1/3            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->3,indexers->[index])
/data_source_1/subdir1/4            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->3,indexers->[index])
/data_source_1/subdir1/5            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->3,indexers->[index])
/data_source_1/subdir2/1            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->3,indexers->[index],dc->[a,b,c])
/data_source_1/subdir2/2            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->3,indexers->[index],dc->[a,b,c])
/data_source_1/subdir2/3            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->3,indexers->[index],dc->[a,b,c])
/data_source_1/subdir2/4            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->3,indexers->[index],dc->[a,b,c])
/data_source_1/subdir2/5            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->3,indexers->[index],dc->[a,b,c])
/data_source_1/subdir2/6            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->3,indexers->[index],dc->[a,b,c])
/data_source_1/subdir2/7            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->3,indexers->[index],dc->[a,b,c])
/data_source_1/subdir2/8            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->3,indexers->[index],dc->[a,b,c])
/data_source_1/subdir2/9            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->10,ncols->3,indexers->[index],dc->[a,b,c])
```

lets find all entries in `/data_source_1/subdir2`:

```
In [20]: [s for s in store if s.startswith('/data_source_1/subdir2/')]
Out[20]:
['/data_source_1/subdir2/1',
 '/data_source_1/subdir2/2',
 '/data_source_1/subdir2/3',
 '/data_source_1/subdir2/4',
 '/data_source_1/subdir2/5',
 '/data_source_1/subdir2/6',
 '/data_source_1/subdir2/7',
 '/data_source_1/subdir2/8',
 '/data_source_1/subdir2/9']
```

and having the keys you can easily select data:

```
In [25]: dfs = [store.select(s, where='a > 5') for s in store if s.startswith('/data_source_1/subdir2/')]

In [26]: [len(df) for df in dfs]
Out[26]: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]

In [29]: dfs = [store.select(s, where='a > 7') for s in store if s.startswith('/data_source_1/subdir2/')]

In [30]: [len(df) for df in dfs]
Out[30]: [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: How would I then list all the elements in group 'aaa'?

Comment: @mgoldwasser, please see update - is that what you are looking for?

Comment: This is helpful - and if I wanted to loop through the children, I think I can do something like this `[my_store.get('/data_source_1/' + child) for child in my_store.get_node('/data_source_1')._v_children.keys()]` but perhaps there is a better way...

Comment: @mgoldwasser, i think it can be done bit easier - see UPDATE2